# Powershell - Script working outside function but not in function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple function that gets files from designated directory filters them with one criteria a then puts the results back. I came up with this as below. It works if it is not placed in a function and when placed in one it only runs `Get-ChildItem` and I have no idea why.
This is my simple code:

```
function Move-AllSigned 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Path
    )
               
    Process {
        $TempPath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath '\1'

        Write-Host $TempPath

        Set-Location -Path $Path
        Get-ChildItem -Name "*sig*" | Move-Item -Destination $TempPath
        Remove-Item *.pdf 
        Set-Location -Path $TempPath
        Move-Item * -Destination $Path
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use the `-Name` parameter on `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: I would recommend the use of `Push` and `Pop` location instead of `Set-Location` or even better, forget about changing directory and work using absolute paths.

Comment: For selecting only the files which contains the name part sig.

Comment: @BalifOne, `-Name` is unrelated to the _matching_ behavior of the cmdlet. It merely requests that path _strings_  (relative to the input path) rather than _objects_ be output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I have no explanation for your symptom, you can *bypass* it by streamlining your code and avoiding `Set-Location` calls (which are best avoided, because they change the current location *session-wide*):

```bash
Remove-Item (Join-Path $Path *.pdf) -Exclude *sig* -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

The above removes all `.pdf` files in folder `$Path` that do not have substring `sig` in their name - which is what I understand your intent to be.

---

Wrapped in a function (error handling omitted):

```bash
function Remove-AllUnsigned {

  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='None')]
  param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [string] $Path,
      [switch] $Force
  )

  # Ask for confirmation, unless -Force was passed.
  # Caveat: The default prompt response is YES, unfortunately.
  if (-not $Force -and -not $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue($Path, "Remove all unsigned PDF files from the following path?")) { return }
  
  # Thanks to SupportsShouldProcess, passing -WhatIf to the function
  # is in effect propagated to cmdlets called inside the function.
  Remove-Item (Join-Path $Path *.pdf) -Exclude *sig*

}
```

Note:

- Since the function isn't designed to accept *pipeline input*, there is no need for a `process` block (though it wouldn't hurt).
- Since *instant deletion* can be dangerous, `$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue()` is used to prompt the user for confirmation by default - unless you explicitly pass `-Force`

  - That the prompt shown by [`$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue) defaults to YES as the response is unfortunate; [GitHub issue #9428](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9428) suggest introducing a new overload that allows defaulting to NO.
- To make the function itself also support the [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) for *previewing* the operation, property `SupportsShouldProcess` in the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute is set (implicitly to `$true`), but the `ConfirmImpact` property is set to `None`, given that `.ShouldContinue()` will handle the prompting, unconditionally (note that explicitly using `-Confirm` would still cause a `ShouldProcess`-related prompt).