# Powershell - Confirmation before executing command in function

Tags: powershell

I put the following function in my powershell profile
(path from `echo $profile`, mine is like `D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`)

```
function test {
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    ls
}
Set-Alias ggg test
```

with `[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` to prompt confirmation, but I get the following error when running `ggg`

```
At D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:2 char:5
+     [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected attribute 'cmdletbinding'.
At D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:3 char:5
+     ls
+     ~~
Unexpected token 'ls' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedAttribute
```

What is the right way to confirm before executing command in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test {
   $confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to continue? [y to continue] "
    if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
        ls
    }
}
Set-Alias ggg test
```

More info see here: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/powershell-yes-no-prompt/

Answer (score 6):

You were on the right track using `SupportsShouldProcess`, however it's missing [`ConfirmImpact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2#confirmimpact) with [`ConfirmImpact` set to **High**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.confirmimpact?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). This way you define that your function is a ***high risk function*** and PowerShell always asks for confirmation. This is also determined by your [`$ConfirmPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#confirmpreference) which, by default, is set to **High**:

> High: PowerShell prompts for confirmation before running cmdlets or functions with a high risk.

If, for example, the preference variable is set to **None**, PowerShell would no longer ask you to confirm the action.

```bash
function test {
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param([string] $myParam)

    if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess([string] $myParam)) {
        Get-ChildItem $myParam
    }
}
```

Then if we try to call the function:

```
PS /> test C:\
```

The following confirmation prompt would appear:

```
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "test" on target "C:\".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Lastly, [`Cmdlet.ShouldProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.shouldprocess?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) has many [**Overloads**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.shouldprocess?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#overloads) which offer a more detailed way of asking for confirmation. The one currently used on the `test` function is the simplest one.

As for the error you're seeing when trying to run your function, this happens because the function has a [`cmdletbinding` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2) declaration making your function and [Advanced Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) but it's missing a [`param` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2) even if the function does not have any parameters it should be there. In addition, a function that `SupportsShouldProcess` **must call `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)` to prompt for confirmation**.

```bash
function test {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

- [Bolton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73004207/45375) provides a pragmatic *workaround* for your problem, by creating a *custom* confirmation prompt.
- [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73004993/45375) shows a proper

  ```
  $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)
  ```

  implementation for *conditional* prompting.
- For an example of implementing an *unconditional* prompt with

  ```
  $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue(...)
  ```

  (explanation below), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498948/45375).

Let me try to complement these answers by providing a systematic overview:

**PowerShell has *two independent mechanisms* for making [advanced (cmdlet-like) functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) prompt for confirmation**:

- ***Conditional* confirmation prompts**, based on 

  ```
  $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)
  ```

   calls - note the word **Process** - which integrate with the  **[common `-Confirm` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm)** and the related **[`$ConfirmPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#confirmpreference)**, and implicitly also enable support for the **[common `-WhatIf` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-whatif)** and the related **[`$WhatIfPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#whatifpreference)**.

  - This mechanism requires:

    - A [`[CmdletBinding(...)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute) attribute above the `param(...)` block (which is what makes a function an *advanced* (cmdlet-like) one), with the the `ShouldProcess` property set to `$true` and, optionally, the `Confirm` property set to one of `'Low'`, `'Medium'` or `'Default'` (default is `'Medium'`; see the [`System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact) enumeration)
    - Guarding the actions the function (or script) is designed to perform with an `if` statement that calls the `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` method and only performs the actions if `$true` is returned.

      - However, note that **prompting is expected to occur *once per input object***, in the `process` block of advanced functions (i.e, those that accept *pipeline input*, as is typical). PowerShell *automatically* handles responses that pertain to *all* (subsequent) input objects in subsequent calls, (`[A] Yes to All` or `[L] No to All`), by automatically returning `$true` or `$false` in subsequent calls.
      - The ***default* prompt response** - selected by just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> - is ***invariably* `[Y] Yes`**, i.e. confirmation of the intent to process (the input object at hand).
  - **Whether a confirmation prompt *will actually be shown*** on invocation can be controlled as follows / depends on the following:

    - To *suppress* prompting, pass `-Confirm:$false` or, for scope-wide effect, set `$ConfirmPreference = 'None'`.
    - To *explicitly request prompting*, use `-Confirm` (or `-Confirm:$true`)
    - Otherwise, prompting will only occur if the value of `$ConfirmPreference` - which defaults to `'High'` - is *equal to or less than* the command's declared confirm-impact level.

      - For instance, the standard `Remove-Item` cmdlet's declared confirm-impact level is `Medium`, so if you set `$ConfirmPreference = 'Medium'`, `Remove-Item` calls (that do not use `-Confirm:$false`) will prompt for confirmation before deleting files.
- ***Unconditional* confirmation prompts**, based on 

  ```
  $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue(...)
  ```

   calls - note the word **Continue**, which are *unrelated* to the common parameters / preference variables mentioned above.

  - This mechanism requires:

    - A `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute above the `param(...)` block, so as to make it an *advanced* function, which enables access to the [automatic `$PSCmdlet` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscmdlet), but requires *no* properties of that attribute to be set.
    - Guarding the actions the function (or script) is designed to perform with an `if` statement that calls the `$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue()` method and only performs the actions if `$true` is returned.

      - Unlike with the `.ShouldProcess()` method, **a prompt is normally only shown *once*** per function invocation, and in the two-parameter overload only shows `[Y] Yes` and `[N] No` choices.

        - However, other overloads allow you to show `[A] Yes to All` or `[L] No to All` choices too, but - unlike with `.ShouldProcess` - you must *manually* manage skip prompting / processing in calls for subsequent input objects based on these choices, which are returned via `[ref]` parameters.
      - The ***default* prompt response** - selected by just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> - is **`[Y] Yes`** too, but you **can change it to `[N] No`** by using the overload that has a `hasSecurityImpact` parameter and passing `$false` to it.

        - Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2.x, doing so *invariably* also shows the `[A] Yes to All` or `[L] No to All` choices, which may be undesired - see [GitHub issue #9428](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9428).
  - **There is *no* standard mechanism for *suppressing* such a prompt**, however, **by convention**, commands ***should* implement a `-Force` switch** to do that.

    - An example is the [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) cmdlet *in Windows PowerShell*, which prompts for confirmation by default, but allows use of `-Force` to suppress the prompt.

**You may *combine* these two mechanisms**, though the only good reason to do so is if you want to support `-WhatIf` functionality in addition to unconditional prompting - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498948/45375) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a good description @mklement0 :-)